# resolv.conf limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I've got a machine (Debian jessie) used to "jump" to another machines, with different domains.... actually many domains.

As `man resolv.conf` tell us, search list for host-name lookup is limited up to 6 domains or 256 characters.

How can I increase the number of domains lookup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) for resolv.conf

> In glibc 2.25 and earlier, the search list is limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters.  Since glibc 2.26, the search list is unlimited.

As such, upgrading glibc should resolve this issue.
For [Debians](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=glibc) Buster and after, along with [Ubuntus](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/glibc) 17.10 and after, the package version of glibc is at or above 2.26, and only requires an `apt` update. It is possible to upgrade by hand if necessary otherwise.

[RHEL8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/8.0_release_notes/index) is baselined on glibc version 2.28 so no update is required; (and [unreasonable](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4496771) for RHEL7 and earlier). Per [distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=fedora), Fedora 27 was the first to implement glibc 2.26.

Comment: Verified! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This question has been asked off and on since the 1990s.  It's still the same answer.

As Jakub Jelinek of RedHat said 10 years ago, this limit is hardwired into the BIND DNS client library that is contained within GNU libc.  It's not configurable at run-time, and it's unlikely to be altered by operating system distributors as that breaks binary compatibility with some third-party programs that use this part of GNU libc.

Of course, if one is capable one can always change the parameter, and recompile from source both GNU libc and all of the programs that use it.  However, this is a lot of work just to make

```
ssh pescado
```

look in more than 6 places in the DNS namespace tree to find a machine named `pescado`.  ☺

### Further reading

- Jakub Jelinek (2005-09-14). [*DNS resolver's 'MAXDNSRCH 6' value is too small*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=168253#1).  168253.  RedHat bugzilla.
- Jakub Jelinek (2006-12-15) .  [*RFE: More search domains in /etc/resolv.conf*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=219778#1).  219778.  RedHat bugzilla.
- Jean-Marc Pouchoulon (2002-04-25). [*resolv.conf manage more than 6 domains*](http://bind-users.isc.narkive.com/OeHqp2if/resolv-conf-manage-more-than-6-domains).  bind-users.

Answer (score 2):

You can't increase the number of search domains.

However, you can:

1. add entries to `/etc/hosts` with the IP address, full hostname, and a short alias.  NOTE: that if the host's IP address changes you will have to update the `/etc/hosts` entry, so this a) defeats the purpose of DNS, and b) is likely to be an annoying "solution" in the medium-to-long term.
2. if by "jump to other machines", you mean`ssh` to them, you can add definitions for hosts in your `~/.ssh/config` file.  You can then ssh to those hosts using either the fully-qualified-domain name OR the short name you give it in the config.

e.g.

```
Host foo
   Hostname foo.example.com
   User cas
```

`ssh foo` would attempt to ssh to foo.example.com with remote username cas.

Comment: We've got an huge environment... we're talking about 50 different domains and 3000 hosts.

Comment: `~/.ssh/config` could be generated by a script.  as could an `/etc/hosts` file.  and as could a DNS zonefile that consisted of little more than CNAME aliases to real hostnames (but doing that would end up with bogus names in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts` file).  6 search domains is the limit and there aren't many ways to work around it.

Comment: I do agree it is far better to do something at application level, than trying to find ways of having so many domain. Finding a way to have 50 domains in DNS means having 200 requests of DNS at worst, 100 as average each time a DNS request is made.

Answer (score -6):

As per the manual for resolv.conf, yes indeed the max limit for domain entries is 6.

If you'd like to use more than 6 domains then you can use local caching nameserver such as dnsmasq for example.

Here is a step-by-step guide how to do that:

```
 https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq
```

Comment: A name server is a web server that has DNS software installed on it, particularly a server that is managed by a web host that is specifically designated for managing the domain names that are associated with all of the hosting provider's accounts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server). So do your homework before you reply:-)

Comment: "resolv.conf" manual: "The search list is currently limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters."

Comment: Ostendali, @cas keep your comments civil and about the technical aspects of the answer. Take it to [chat] if you want to indulge your penchant for sarcasm.